# Making visualvm to look onto the jars

Tags: visualvm, jvisualvm

Hi I am totally new to VisualVm. I would like to know whether there is any configuration to be done for making visualvm to look onto the jars. I am using ubuntu and openjdk version 1.8.0_131. I installed visualvm and its showing eclipse and is not onto the jar.I tried giving the jdk path in visualvm.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to set the Java_Home.
VisualVM is not require any Jar files. Please go to your JDK folder (in Bin) select the visual vm and open the file( Run as administrator ).In eclipse you have to set the launcher (Eclipse Launcher or VisualVM Launcher).

Comment: I am asked  to select a launcher eclipse or visulavm... when I select visualvm  and run its throwing error:An internal error occurred during: "Launching InfraConfiguratorTest".
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Start the Eclipse from the command prompt ; C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin" -clean(windows)

Comment: Go to eclipse Folder where its located exactly then type eclipse -clean